# Having trouble writing my first bash script

Tags: linux, bash

ok I am writing my first bash script in ubuntu 10.04.

The file is on my desktop: `/home/myuser/Desktop`

The file is called `hello-world`

The file contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

I open a command line and run:

> /home/myuser/Desktop/hello-world

It tells me permition is denied. So I run it again with sudo, it asks me for my password, I type it in, hit return.

I get this output.

> sudo:
>   /home/myuser/Desktop/hello-world:
>   command not found

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod +x hello-world`

Answer (score 4):

Your script probably is not set to be executable. Try:

```
chmod u+x /home/myuser/Desktop/hello-world
```

Answer (score 3):

If your script is called test.sh then do the following...

`$ chmod +x test.sh`

followed by

`$ ./test.sh`

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark the script as executable. Run `chmod +x hello-world` to add the executable bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
sh /home/myuser/Desktop/hello-world
```

which will execute the script without it needing to be set as executable.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `bash /home/myuser/Desktop/hello-world` to conform to the OP's choice of shell?